# Существует ли союз «когда… то» с временным значением?

Tags: синтаксис, союзы, спп, сложное-предложение, придаточное-предложение

*Когда мы приходим на работу, то думаем: «Буду просто хорошо выполнять свои обязанности — и начальство меня заметит»*.

«То» добавлено для благозвучия и более «мягкого» структурного перехода от придаточного к главному. Прочтите без «то» — получится несуразно. Но проблема в том, что я ещё не встречал составного союза «когда… то» с временным значением. В значении «если… то» вводящий придаточное условное есть у Чехова:

*Надеюсь, что когда я получу Анну второй степени, то его сиятельство не будет иметь повода сказать мне то же самое* (А. П. Чехов, «Анна на шее», 1895 г.).

**Вопрос** — в заголовке.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Двойной союз "когда..., то" действительно существует в разных справочниках.
https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/39-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_fonetika__slovoobrazovanie__morfologiya_i_orfografiya/stages/695-3102_soyuz_morfologicheskii_razbor_soyuzov_pravopisanie_soyuzov.html

В любом случае союз "когда..., то" является временным — даже если по смыслу есть оттенок условия (за счёт совершенной формы глагола будущего времени). Разница в регулярности действия: *когда я получу* — единоразовое действие при совершенной форме глагола;  *когда мы приходим* — регулярное действие при несовершенной форме.
Ели изменить форму глаголов на совершенную, то звучит лучше — но функция и вид союза при этом не меняются:
*Когда мы придём на работу, то сделаем следующее...*

Есть временной составной союз — *когда..., то тогда и*.
http://rusgram.narod.ru/1669-1688.html
В случае с "когда..., то" — "тогда и" опускается и подразумевается по смыслу.

Comment: "когда... то" - это вполне может быть условие.

Comment: Когда бы понял Ионафан //
Коварный Трифонов обман, //
Не верил речи лицемерной, //
Даров не взял бы, то, наверно, //
Вернулся б невредим и жив он, (Бранд, "Корабль дураков")

А в дураках остался б Трифон.

Comment: Условие или не условие по смыслу - а союз-то временным остаётся - именно это имел в виду.

Comment: У нас ни единоразовое действие, ни регулярное — у нас общий факт.

Comment: Просто "когда я получу" - это ведь один раз будет (момент получения), а "когда мы приходим" - приходим на работу ведь регулярно.

Comment: @ВасилийЕфименко Дело вот в чём. Оно не сильно звучит, потому что сам вопрос "когда?" особо не задают при настоящем: *когда ты ходишь в школу? когда вы открываете здание? когда вы на смене? когда вы приходите на роботу?* - плохо звучит. Вопросы заменяют на: *в какие дни? во сколько? с которого часа?* А вопрос "когда?" в основном употребляется по отношению к одному конкретному действию. Это "точное" местоимение. А в "когда мы приходим на работу" особо и нет конкретики. И лучше звучит, если заменить глагол настоящего времени на деепричастие: *Приходя на работу, мы думаем: «Буду просто хорошо...*

Comment: Поясню смысл. В предложении имеется в виду обобщённый факт: «когда мы приходим на работу» — «когда мы начинаем свою трудовую деятельность после университета», а не «когда мы приходим каждый день в офис». Поэтому используется повествовательная форма несовершенного вида.

Comment: Ааа. Это похоже на то предложение про зелёные коктейли. Тоже стилистическая неточность. Но тут сразу воспринимается именно прямой смысл - приходим каждый день. Тогда лучше сказать, что начинаем работать. Да и вообще смысл странный: нельзя же всех ровнять по одной манере. Кто-то сразу пытается выделиться, выслужиться, чтобы понравится начальству. А кто-то - активно общаться с начальством, чтобы подружиться. Да и думаю, что в этом смысле "приходим на работу" - разговорный вариант.